# Role of number of db connections in application configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have been working on an application for around some time. Its old application written in C++ and then on C#.

It has entry in the registry for the DBConnectionsFrontEnd for front end which is in asp.net and the on DBConnectionsService for windows service. I could recall recall that db has connection pool and pool has the limit and all. But when i started thinking about it i really felt like i dont know the exact answer. It is been there for very long and those who have designed this mush have thought it for something. Ran out of DB connections in log attracted my attention to this issue. We increased the number in connection and that addressed the issue.

Can someone please help me get my basics clear about this Or point me to some resource to better understand answers to the questions like following.  why this Number of db connections has to be configurable value ? How and What role it plays in application design ? What will happen if its not considered ? Does a database has constraints on number of connections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, ADO.Net maintains a pool of connections to the database due to various reasons including the fact that they are somewhat expensive to obtain.

By default, ADO.Net creates 100 entries in the pool, so you configuration will adjust this number for performance purposes.

[MSDN contains a lot more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) on this subject.